# Variable of type int8_t always gets value of 0 from scanf

Tags: c

This program will work if the type of `num` is `int`.  But when change it to `int8_t`, `num` will always be 0 after `scanf()`.

Is this because of the `%d` in `scanf`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
void convert(int8_t, int8_t);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int8_t num;
    int8_t b;
    printf("enter a number:\n");
    while (1 == scanf("%d", &num)) {   
        scanf("%d", &b);
        printf("%d %d\n", num, b);
        printf("Code: ");
        convert(num, b);
        putchar('\n');
        printf("enter a integer (q to quit):\n");
    }
    printf("done.\n");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void convert(int8_t n, int8_t base) {
    if (n >= base)
        convert(n / base, base);
    printf("%d", n % base);
    return;
}
```

Comment: 1) Read the manual for `scanf`, 2) enable compiler warnings, 3) don't lie to the compiler.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer check out the format section

Answer (score 5):

You pass wrong argument to `scanf` ,`%d` expects address of an `int`.

You can make use of macro `SCNd8` to take input for `int8_t`. Header `<intypes.h>`.

```
scanf("%"SCNd8, &b);
```

And macro `PRId8` to print its value .

Answer (score 1):

The `%d` format specifier for `scanf` expects the argument to be the address of an `int`, which is 4 or 8 bytes on most systems.  You're passing it the address of a `int8_t`, which is only 1 byte.  So `scanf` writes the resulting value into 4-8 bytes instead of 1, resulting in undefined behavior.

You need to use `%hhd`, which expects a pointer to `char` (which is the same as `int8_t`) as its argument.

Comment: The correct format specifieri is in `inttypes.h`: `SCNd8`.